# How to delete "X" lines, when found "Y" line

Tags: python

I have a .txt with contacts like this:

(line 1) `Andrew`
(line 2) `andrew@email.com`
(line 3) `314657463`
(line 4) `Ariana`
(line 5) `ariana@email.com`
(line 6) `1026479657`
(line 7) `.`
(line n) `...`

(each value is in a diferent line)

I am trying to make a code (Python) to delete 1 full contact (name, email and phone number) given the NAME.

The thing is, I haven't been able to delete the email and the phone number.

This is what I tried:

```
def delete_someone():
    Y=input("Enter the full name:")
    archivo=open("agenda.txt", "r")
    count_lineas= archivo.readlines()
    archivo.close()
    archivo1= open("agenda.txt", "w")
    for line in count_lineas:
        if line.strip("\n")!= Y:
            archivo1.write(line)
    archivo1.close()
```

Comment: Are they on different lines or same lines?

Comment: Also, the contact will always remain in this format?

Comment: If you detect the name, you could set a flag to 0, and count up for each new line. If that flag is under 3, then ignore the line, otherwise write it.

Comment: Yes, the main idea is that it'll always be name-emai-phone number (one line each one).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the `grouper()` function in the [Itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) section of the documentation to process the lines in groups of 3 like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def delete_someone():
    Y = input("Enter the full name: ")
    with open("agenda.txt", "r") as archivo:
        count_lineas = archivo.readlines()

    with open("agenda.txt", "w") as archivo:
        for group in grouper(count_lineas, 3):
            if group[0].rstrip() != Y:
                archivo.writelines(group)

delete_someone()
```

Comment: This is definetly the path people with same need should try! Thanks! The most efficient, mainly because you can easily change if you want to delete the contact, SEARCHING by "name",  "email" or "phone number" (just changing the group[i]).

Comment: Glad to hear you recognized its merits — not sure what the down vote was about, since the voter left no comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the best solution but definitely give a try.

`c.txt`

```
Andrew
andrew@email.com
314657463
Ariana
ariana@email.com
1026479657
```

This code was written assuming that a new contact starts with every 3rd line.

```
x=open('c.txt','r')
test_list=[]
for y in x.readlines():
    #print(y.strip("\n"))
    test_list.append(y.strip("\n"))
while True:
    j=input("Enter a name to delete: ")
    if j in test_list:
        sd=test_list.index(j)
        for i in range(0,3):
            po=test_list.pop(sd)
        f=open('all.txt',"w")
        for j in test_list:
            f.write(j+"\n")
        print("File written successfully")
        break
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter the correct name...\n")
```

Sample Running:

```
Enter a name to delete: Ariana
File written successfully
```

`all.txt`

```
Andrew
andrew@email.com
314657463
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick untested example from my comment. By counting up from 0 after you find a name, you could exclude n lines after you find a match.

```
def delete_someone():
    Y=input("Enter the full name:")
    archivo=open("agenda.txt", "r")
    count_lineas= archivo.readlines()
    archivo.close()
    archivo1= open("agenda.txt", "w")

    delete_counter = float('inf')  # This can be any number above 2 to be honest
    for line in count_lineas:
        if line.strip("\n") == Y:
            delete_counter = 0     # Restart the counter
        if delete_counter > 2:     # Skip the next 2 lines too
            archivo1.write(line)   # Write the 3rd line onwards
        delete_counter += 1
    
    archivo1.close()
```

This won't be the most efficient or fancy solution, its just something easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to only evaluate every third line like this:

```
name = input("Enter the full name:")
with open("agenda.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("agenda.txt", "w") as f:
    for line_index in range(0, len(lines), 3):
        if lines[line_index].strip("\n") != name:
            f.write(lines[line_index])
            f.write(lines[line_index + 1])
            f.write(lines[line_index + 2])
```

This assumes that the format does not change and that the .txt file starts with a "name" line.

Comment: I think this is a nice solution, and a short one. Nevertheless, what if you're asked to delete a full contact based on the "email". [line_index + 1] and [line_index - 1] won't work to adjust the code. I am trying to figure it out how. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could adjust the range in the for loop. The first parameter is the starting value. Set that to one and the email will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little ugly, but use iter() to skip two lines if a match

```
def delete_someone():
    Y=input("Enter the full name:")
    archivo=open("agenda.txt", "r")
    count_lineas= archivo.readlines()
    archivo.close()
    archivo1= open("agenda.txt", "w")
    
    nBlockSize = 3
    it = iter(count_lineas)
    line = next(it,False)
    while line:
        if line.strip("\n")!= Y:
            archivo1.write(line)
        else:
            [next(it,False) for n in range(nBlockSize-1)]

        line = next(it,False)    

    archivo1.close()
```